# Why is this [L] flag failing to prevent application of the next rewrite rule?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I thought the "L" flag was supposed to prevent subsequent rules from being applied.  Yet in this example:

```
RewriteRule foo bar [L]
RewriteRule bar qux
```

I get `http://mysite/foo` rewritten as `http://mysite/qux`.  I expected `http://mysite/bar`.  What am I missing here?

Comment: Are you sure it isn't performing a redirect?

Comment: I'm not sure - how do I check?

Comment: Firebug or a similar browser tool will tell you if a 30X status code was returned by the first request.

Comment: I just see a single GET request in firebug's NET panel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior of the `[L]` flag is quite poorly described in the Apache docs. In order to understand how it works we first need to know how Apache handles RewriteRules. Let's take a simple example

```
RewriteRule ^something /somethingelse #1
RewriteRule ^somewhere /somewhereelse #2 
RewriteRule ^someplace /anotherplace  #3
```

In this situation with multiple rules and no `[L]` flags, if we were to request `/something`, Apache will rewrite that `/somethingelse` (as per #1), then try rules #2 and #3. After all rules are processed it checks if the URL that came out of the RewriteRules is the same as the URL that went in. If it's not, Apache starts processing all the rules again, until input===output (or the maximum number of redirects is met, to prevent infinite loops).

Now, if we change rule #1 and add `[L]` to it, and we request `/something` again, Apache will rewrite it to `/somethingelse` (as per #1), and then stop processing the rules, i.e., it will not process #2 and #3. But then, since the URL that came out is not the same as the URL that went in (that's the crux here), the processing *restarts*, and rules #2 and #3 will be processed anyway (and #1 also, but doesn't do anything anymore).

In your example if you want to prevent `/bar` from being redirected to `/qux` when it was rewritten by the first RewriteRule, you can use

```
RewriteRule foo bar [L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /bar
RewriteRule bar qux
```

That will rewrite `/bar` to `/qux` *only* if the user specifically requested `/bar`, and not if the URL was rewritten from `/foo` to `/bar` first.

The trick here is that `%{THE_REQUEST}` contains the exact HTTP header that was used for the request, and doesn't change when you rewrite the URL, so using that variable you can always check what the original request was for (in contrast to `%{REQUEST_URI}`, which does change on every rewrite).

Comment: Unfortunately that breaks HEAD and POST requests.  Better to rewrite the transformations to avoid the problem.

Comment: You can replace `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /bar` with `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST|HEAD)\ /bar` if you want to support HEAD and POST requests as well.

Comment: Or you can just reverse the order of the rules

Answer (score 1):

From the `mod_rewrite` [introduction](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html):

> Be sure to configure [mod_rewrite's](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) log level to one of the trace
>   levels using the [LogLevel](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#loglevel) directive. It is indispensable in
>   debugging problems with mod_rewrite configuration, since it will tell
>   you exactly how each rule is processed.

To turn on mod_rewrite tracing in Apache 2.4 you can use

```
LogLevel info mod_rewrite:trace3
```

However, in Apache 2.2 (which is the current favorite for production) you have to use

```
RewriteLog "/var/log/apache2/rewrite.log"
RewriteLogLevel 3
```

Your config

```
RewriteRule foo bar [L]
RewriteRule bar qux
```

is problematic because it must be run only once to work the way you want.  The [L flag in 2.2](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_l) doesn't do what you think when the rule is used in a Directory or .htaccess context.

> If you are using RewriteRule in either .htaccess files or in
>    sections, it is important to have some understanding of
>   how the rules are processed. The simplified form of this is that once
>   the rules have been processed, the rewritten request is handed back to
>   the URL parsing engine to do what it may with it. It is possible that
>   as the rewritten request is handled, the .htaccess file or 
>   section may be encountered again, and thus the ruleset may be run
>   again from the start. Most commonly this will happen if one of the
>   rules causes a redirect - either internal or external - causing the
>   request process to start over.

However, moving those rules to a service config or virtual host context does work.  (Verified on my local server.)

In general you want to write rules so it doesn't matter how many times they are processed.  If you absolutely cannot do that, I still don't like using `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /bar` to avoid looping or even `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[^ ]+ /bar` but I don't have a have suggestion at the moment for Apache 2.2.

Apache 2.4 has the [END](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_end) flag for just this situation.